# BA network policy-CKA

Tags: kubernetes

if we have a pod in one namespace created for eg app-space, pod name: busybox
and if the pod is not having any labels on it, can we apply network policy ?
[image]

how does the namespace selector field  highlighted in yellow work?

does this mean that any pod with labels project=myproject will only be allowed in that namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 places in netpol where label selectors are used..

1. .spec.podselector.MatchLabels

in the example above that label selector is. role=db

That selector determines which pod the netpol is going to get applied to.  Also, remember that netpol is a namespaced object ( you can check that out from doing kubectl api-resources).   So, since the value of metadata.namespace is default, this policy will apply to any pod in the default namespace that has labe=db

2). The optional namespace selector in the spec.ingress[*].namespaceSelector.matchLabels

In the example you show this is project=myproject. ( this could be on the egress side to as spec.egress[*].namespaceSelector.matchLabels)

This label selector means from who the traffic is allowed (for the ingress example)

So, in the example above it's allowed  for the namespace whose label is project=myproject

Remember you can label a ns also.

for instance:  kubectl label ns project  project=myproject

The yaml for the ns project would then look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
 name: project
 labels:
   project: myproject
```

Comment: what if labels are not given for the other pods : 
how do we select other namespace by name  in namespaceselector ?